# ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: vb.net, executereader

Can you explain why I am getting this error?

ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized

```
Protected Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim name = txtUserName.Text.Trim
    Dim Pass = txtPassword.Text.Trim

    Try

        Dim conn As SqlConnection
        conn = DataBaseFunc.OpenConnection()

        Dim sqlSt As String = "select * FROM AdminLog WHERE AdminName = '" & name & "' AND AdminPassword = '" & Pass & "'"
        Dim SelCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlSt, conn)

        Dim RrecSet As SqlDataReader

        RrecSet = SelCmd.ExecuteReader()

        If RrecSet.Read() Then
            Session("Admin") = RrecSet("AdminName")
            Response.Redirect("~/AdminPages/AdminHome.aspx")
        Else
            lblMsg.Text = "<p>Rong Username or Password</p>"
            txtUserName.Text = ""
            txtPassword.Text = ""
            txtUserName.Focus()

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
End Sub
```

DataBaseFunc

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic


Public Class DataBaseFunc
    Public Shared Sub EnsureOpenConnection(ByRef conn As SqlConnection)
        Try
            If conn.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub


    Public Shared Function OpenConnection() As SqlConnection
        Try
            Dim ConnString As String = "server =.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BloodDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
            If conn.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
            Return conn
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Since the msg clearly indicates a Connection issue, the code for `DataBaseFunc.OpenConnection()` would be nice to see.  Also, Parameterized queries would prevent SQL injection (look it up) and you ought not store Passwords in DBs (esp Admin!).

Comment: what sort of change?

Comment: Get rid of the do-nothing Try/Catch in OpenConnection so that when something goes wrong you'll know about it.  A Try/Catch is not supposed to hide problems from the developer

Comment: is it possible for you to give me updated code? please? i am really not good at this. and i really dont want to screw up

Comment: You have to do *some* work yourself.  If something is wrong with the connection string or something else fails, you will never know about it because of the empty Try/Catch; if it returns `Nothing` you can use `Nothing` as a valid connection!.  I cant post an answer because no one knows for sure what the answer is because your code is not reporting the problem.  Get rid of the Try/Catch and there is a good chance NET will give you an actionable exception message.

Comment: so i should remove whole of try to catch code? can i contact you on whatsapp or something

Comment: remove `try`, `catch` , `return Nothing` and `End Try`, not the code inside the block that opens the connection.  This may reveal the **real** problem which you can use to update/edit your post with the relevant info

Answer (score 0):

Change your `DataBaseFunc` code to something like this, and `MsgBox` might give you a better understanding of error.
Having Try/Catch with no actual code inside (like `MsgBox(ex.toString)` or `println(ex.toString)` is useless. After you do and try this, report as with further information.

```
Public Class DataBaseFunc
        Public Shared Sub EnsureOpenConnection(ByRef conn As SqlConnection)
            Try
                If conn.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Open()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
               MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Sub


        Public Shared Function OpenConnection() As SqlConnection
            Try
                Dim ConnString As String = "server =.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BloodDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
                Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
                If conn.State <> Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    conn.Open()
                End If
                Return conn
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: i have got a pretty long message which i cant copy. i can take a screenshot. can i email or something to you?

Comment: i have got a pretty long error message, can i post pics here? or email it to you?

Comment: You can add image links to your question.

Comment: Post the link of image as text, do not add an image. If you still can't do that, but I see no reason why that couldn't happen, just paste img link here as a comment.